# Box Shadow is not showing in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My Box Shadow is not showing in IE7 and IE8.

```
#bodyContainer{
 background: url(../images/site_bg.png)  repeat ;
 margin: 0px auto;
    width:1000px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    /*background:#FFFFFF;*/
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #000000;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/), which emulates [some CSS3 properties](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/) in older versions of IE.

It supports `box-shadow` ([except for](https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/3) the `inset` keyword).

and

There are article about [CSS3 Box Shadow in Internet Explorer](http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/) and [Box-shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/).

Hope this helps

also you can use

```
style="FILTER: DropShadow(Color=#0066cc, OffX=5, OffY=-3, Positive=1);width:300px;font-size:20pt;"

style="filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropShadow (OffX='-2', OffY='-2', Color='#c0c0c0', Positive='true')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the non-standard IE filter property. See [this article](http://hedgerwow.appspot.com/demo/shadow)

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to `Box-shadow`'s [MDN compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow#Browser_compatibility), Box-shadow doesn't support in IE7 and IE8.

Check the same link (Notes section) for more info on alternative properties like [Dropshadow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532985%28VS.85,loband%29.aspx) and [shadow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28VS.85,loband%29.aspx) properties.

**Syntax**:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(sProperties)
```

---

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(sProperties)
```

Answer (score 0):

box-shadow is a feature of CSS3
hence it is not supported below ie9

you can check the compatibity here:

http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

Box-Shadow is not compatible below IE9

Always check compatibility of CSS Properties using following link
http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow